# String to Date using ParseExact fail

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not getting used to convert string to date, can someone help me?

```
String str = "2014-09-10T18:42:17";

DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: his problem is his format string looks nothing like his date string

Comment: Look at your date string and then look at your format. You notice anything?

Comment: Please, I need an example of the correct format !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The string format has to match exactly with the date format.
From MSDN, `ParseExact()`

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.

`Exactly` being the key word here. So in your example the exact string format would be:

```
2014-09-10T18:42:17
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
```

Comment: I tried this way but the visual studio returns me the following mesagem - 
  the name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Add the namespace, `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`

Comment: Help me ! Error 1 A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' is a type not a namespace c:\users\mmurta\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CONVERSAO_PARA_STRING\CONVERSAO_PARA_STRING\Program.cs 5 7 CONVERSAO_PARA_STRING

Comment: `CultureInfo` is the class. Add this exact line `using System.Globalization`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at your source data? It's a date/time represented in ISO 8601 long form

```
2014-09-10T18:42:17
```

Your format specifier, on the other hand is looking for a string in the the form

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
```

where `dd` is the day of the month (01-31), `MM` is the month number (01-12), `yyyy` is the 4-digit year, `HH` is the hour of the day (00-23) and `mm` is the minute (00-59). It will match strings that look like

```
10/09/2014 18:42
```

If you want to match your source data, you need to use this format string:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
```

You might try reading the documentation:

- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks your answer was very good! Thanks for the documentation links!